# Latex \multirow : giving multirow an inverted argument shifts text

Tags: latex, multirow

I want to color a \multirow text but it overwrites the text at the second line. I found out that using \rowcolor{} and \multirow{-2}{text} don't overlay the text. But when using it the whole text shifts up and don't fit with the \rowcolor.

So here is my origin problem:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule
        
        \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Beschreibung} \\
        \hline
        \midrule
        \rowcolor{gray!10}
        \textit{CV\_RETR\_EXTERNAL} & Abfrage der Extremwerte der Außenkontur\\
        
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{CV\_RETR\_LIST}} & \multirow{2}{10cm}{Abfrage aller Konturen in einer Liste und Verknüpfung aller Konturen miteinander. } \\
        &\\
        
        \rowcolor{gray!10}
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{CV\_RETR\_CCOMP}} & \multirow{2}{10cm}{Abfrage aller Konturen mit anschließender Einordnung in einer zweistufigen Hierarchie}\\
        \rowcolor{gray!10}
            &\\
        
        \textit{CV\_RETR\_TREE} &   Abfrage aller Konturen und Rekosntruktion der gesamten Hierarchie.\\
        \hline
        
    \end{tabular}
```

Result:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD5Oj.png)

When changing code to \multirow{-2} the text shifts up.

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule
        
        \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Beschreibung} \\
        \hline
        \midrule
        \rowcolor{gray!10}
        \textit{CV\_RETR\_EXTERNAL} & Abfrage der Extremwerte der Außenkontur\\
        
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{CV\_RETR\_LIST}} & \multirow{2}{10cm}{Abfrage aller Konturen in einer Liste und Verknüpfung aller Konturen miteinander. } \\
        &\\
        
        \rowcolor{gray!10}
            \multirow{-2}{*}{\textit{CV\_RETR\_CCOMP}} & \multirow{-2}{10cm}{Abfrage aller Konturen mit anschließender Einordnung in einer zweistufigen Hierarchie}\\
        \rowcolor{gray!10}
            &\\
        
        \textit{CV\_RETR\_TREE} &   Abfrage aller Konturen und Rekosntruktion der gesamten Hierarchie.\\
        \hline
        
    \end{tabular}
```

Result:
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtaZU.png)

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just forget `\multirow` here. What I suppose you want is to center the left column entries with respect to their right column cells. The easiest way to do this is to use a `m{10cm}` spec for the right column and then just enter the values.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lm{10cm}}
        \toprule
        
        \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Beschreibung} \\
        \hline
        \midrule
        \rowcolor{gray!10}
        \textit{CV\_RETR\_EXTERNAL} & Abfrage der Extremwerte der Außenkontur\\
        
        {\textit{CV\_RETR\_LIST}} & Abfrage aller Konturen in einer Liste und Verknüpfung aller Konturen miteinander. \\

        \rowcolor{gray!10}
            {\textit{CV\_RETR\_CCOMP}} & Abfrage aller Konturen mit anschließender Einordnung in einer zweistufigen Hierarchie \\

        \textit{CV\_RETR\_TREE} &   Abfrage aller Konturen und Rekosntruktion der gesamten Hierarchie.\\
        \hline
        
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]